# Does IP fail-over help me?

Tags: ip

I'm having dedicated server from OVH and I have ordered IP failover.
Now I'm wondering is it an additional IP?
The reason I ordered it is:
I'm running an application which uses port 3900, and I need to run second same application on port 3900 (on that additional IP) also. (changing the port is not a solution)

So will I be able to have one application on first.ip.xxx.xxx:3900 and second application on failover.ip.ibought.xxx:3900? Or I have bought totally different thing?

Summarized:
Is IP failover I bought an additional IP for my server?

Comment: You can put both services into a linux container and expose the service on whatever port you want on the host machine. Additional ip addresses are not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you've chosen right: in OVH, the ip failovers are additional IPs to be used on a virtual network card.
After creating the "new network card" (eth0:0) and assigning an IP, you will be able to serve whatever you want with that ip... on the same port.
You must, before using it and after having completed the configuration, enter their control panel and associate the IP to your dedicated server, making the OVH routers know how to forward that IP.
I did it once, when I had another dedicated and, after asking them how did the additional IPs work in OVH, they told me I can use the failovers, that are completely different from what are for example the elastic IPs on Amazon.
Anyway, more information about it are here: http://help.ovh.co.uk/IpAlias
In the meantime, good luck with your server and your project! ;-)

Comment: What you're linking to is IP Alias, which is not the same as IP Failover. (see http://help.ovh.co.uk/IpFailover)

Comment: Yes: in your link, under "Install", they show you the installation, that points to http://help.ovh.co.uk/IpAlias :)

Comment: Weird. Why does the page I link to talk about rocking back and  forth between 2 servers and the install page talk about multiple IPs and virtual NICs?

Comment: I have just installed additional IP as shown in the manual and it works perfectly. IP fail-over as name itself gives fuss :/

Comment: Probably it is just about how OVH is naming the IP failovers, however, you need to configure the virtual IPs on the machine using virtual network cards, and then you can "connect" the IP to a machine or another one (as far as I know, you can't connect the IP to two machines for a load balance for example, which is another different service they offer). This is pretty much what OVH allows you to do with IP failovers. Then, using the OVH APIs, you can switch them using heartbeat or some other daemons, allowing your services to become highly available and not letting a server down unplug you.

Comment: @DedaSpale Yes... I had your exact doubts when I did buy the failovers, and that's why I asked OVH support (that is not that fast btw) "why are they called failover if they don't... automatically failover?". The answer was that you must take care of failovers, they just give you the IP. This is how OVH works btw: they offer you the infrastructure, you must add your own software, because they really don't care about it. The infrastructure works, so wondering why the software doesn't it's up to you. Anyway, I'm glad to have helped you solve your problem ;-)

Comment: Well, I'm glad you guys were able to figure it out - that would have confused me. IP failover on every other hosting company I've worked with describes what I answered as.

Comment: @Marcus_33, well, that's what this website is for... and without experience with OVH, since the name is "weird", nobody could tell otherwise :-P

Answer (score 2):

Nope. What you bought is not a second IP. You purchased a mirrored second server that will take over on the same IP address in the event that the first server becomes unreachable.

Here's a [good explanation](http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/10/28/ip-failover-high-availability-explained)

Comment: He did not buy a second server. If he want, he *can* use the fail over IP with another mirrored server, but this is not the case.

Comment: This answer is incorrect (would vote down, but I do not have enough rep on this Stack Exchange site ;))